# Path-following algorithm and suggestions for mecanum robot

Tags: wheeled-robot, navigation, algorithm, path-planning, precise-positioning

I have a robot with four mecanum wheels (blue square) that can move in an open-space room.
The position x,y of the robot is measured in a very accurate way by a fixed position sensor (red circle) that is placed in the origin of the place and has coordinates (0,0,0). The position of the robot is updated at 10Hz.

I want to make the robot follow different paths like the one from A to B as showed in the picture (in green color).

What is the best and accurate way to do that? 
I think I should have to create the path like a series of x,y points and make the robot move towards them but I don't know how to derive the motion equations.

Can you give me some advices or examples, please?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Let's suppose you have a required (continuous) trajectory in the form of an equation that you want to follow, for example take a straight line (whose equation is y=2x+5), you can break it down into discrete points and generate a velocity profile out of this trajectory, the calculated velocity profile could be fed to inverse kinematic equations **[1]** of robot (omni-platform) for calculating the angular velocities of wheel which will be required to follow that above path (straight line in our example).

**[1]:** https://www.researchgate.net/publication/308570348_Inverse_kinematic_implementation_of_four-wheels_mecanum_drive_mobile_robot_using_stepper_motors

Answer (score 0):

You could try to implement a [pure pursuit controller](https://www.ri.cmu.edu/pub_files/pub3/coulter_r_craig_1992_1/coulter_r_craig_1992_1.pdf).